# Siunitx error: "Runaway argument? Paragraph ended before \SI was complete"

Tags: errors, siunitx

Do `siunitx` macros need special characters after them? The below code throws a 'runaway argument' error. But if I add a `;` after `[\$]` the code does compile. And if I add a `.`, the code compiles, but the `.` disappears. What's the logic here?

```
\documentclass[]{memoir}  
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}

\LaTeX costs \SI{0}[\$]

\end{document}
```

Comment: You need the 2nd mandatory argument which is the unit (in this case blank) `\SI{0}[\$]{}`.  The syntax is `\SI[<options>]{<number>}[<pre-unit>]{<unit>}` (see p.4 `siunitx` manual).  Recall for LaTeX, brackets are optional arguments, braces are mandatory arguments.

Answer (score 4):

Converting my upvoted comment into an answer, at Torbjorn's request.

For this problem, you need the 2nd mandatory argument which is the unit (in this case blank)

```
\SI{0}[\$]{}
```

The syntax is `\SI[<options>]{<number>}[<pre-unit>]{<unit>}` (see p.4 siunitx manual). Recall for LaTeX, brackets are optional arguments, braces are mandatory arguments.

```
\documentclass[]{memoir}  
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}

\LaTeX{} costs \SI{0}[\$]{}

on special this week for \SI{6}[\$]{\!^{\scriptscriptstyle 99}}!

\end{document}
```

[image]